# What is wrong with my UVa code

Tags: c++

I tried to solve this problem in UVa but I am getting a wrong answer and I cant seem to find the error
http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=2525

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int t,j,k,i=1;
char a[1000];

while(scanf("%d",&t)!=EOF && t)
{
int sum=0; 
getchar();

gets(a);

k=strlen(a);

for(j=0;j<k;j++)
           {     if(a[j]=='a'||a[j]=='d'||a[j]=='g'||a[j]=='j'||a[j]=='m'||a[j]=='p'||a[j]=='t'||a[j]=='w'||a[j]==32)
                sum=sum+1;
                else if(a[j]=='b'||a[j]=='e'||a[j]=='h'||a[j]=='k'||a[j]=='n'||a[j]=='q'||a[j]=='u'||a[j]=='x')
                sum=sum+2;
                else if(a[j]=='c'||a[j]=='f'||a[j]=='i'||a[j]=='l'||a[j]=='o'||a[j]=='r'||a[j]=='v'||a[j]=='y')
                sum=sum+3;
                else if(a[j]=='s'||a[j]=='z')
                sum=sum+4;
            }

printf("Case #%d: %d\n",i,sum);
i++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `while` loop does not seem to be right is it? Do you want to read `t` in each iteration?

Comment: yes t is for the number of cases

Comment: How many times does the number of cases appear in your input? *Do you want to read `t` in **each** iteration?*

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas The number of cases appears once, at the very start of the input. Dividing the workload into: read T and T lines (the workload), process each line, output each line result, should make him consider all these questions and hopefully lead to better code...

Comment: yes @DavidRodríguez-dribeas

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas My code started working after I removed that while loop and used a for loop , can you please explain whats the difference in this code ideone.com/61wssw

Comment: @swapedoc: The difference is that now you only try to read the number once, where it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the problem description there is a single number that indicates the number of texts that will be in the input afterwards. Your original code was trying to read the number before every row of input.

The attempt to read the number in each one of the rows will  fail since the input character set does not include any digits, so you could be inclined to think that there should be no difference. But there is, when you try to read a number it will start by consuming the leading whitespace. If the input is:

> < space >< space >a

The output should be 3 (two '0' and one '2' keys), but the attempt to read the number out of the line will consume the two leading whitespace characters and the later `gets` will read the string `"a"`, rather than `"  a"`. Your count will be off by the amount of leading whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

1. separate your code into functions that do specific things: read the data from the file, calculate the number of key presses for each input, output the result

Benefit:
You can test each function independently. It is also easier to reason about the code.

1. The maximum size of an input is 100, this means you only need an array of 101 characters( including the final `\0`) for each input, not 1000.
2. Since this question is also tagged `C++` try to use `std::vector` and `std::string` in your code.
3. The inner `for` seems right at a cursory glance. The befit of having a specialized function that computes the number of key presses is that you can easily verify it does the correct thing. Make sure you check it thoroughly.

Comment: earlier I used 101 characters but I was still getting that same wrong answer.

Comment: @swapedoc The fact that you got the wrong answer has little to go with the 101 characters. Delete all the code and start again, writing specialized function as per my answer. Test each function independently. Come back if there are any new issues.

Comment: @swapedoc For starters, "The first line of input will be a positive integer T where T denotes the number of test cases. T lines will then follow" from the problem description suggests having a file as input. I also see no hint of my *Delete all the code and start again, writing specialized function as per my answer* request

Comment: this time I calculated value of sum in each case and found out that compiler is not reading the first character of the string,why is that so http://ideone.com/cAKdaV @Andrei

Comment: @swapedoc your changes are irrelevant... the problem states "The first line of input will be a positive integer T where T denotes the number of test cases. T lines will then follow each containing only spaces and lower case letters. Each line will contain at least 1 and at most 100 characters. " Since you code uses `namespace std` this is clearly C++. Please write a function that produces/fills a `std::vector<std::string>` containing the test cases you need to process.

Comment: My code started working after I removed that while loop and used a for loop , can you please explain whats the difference in this code http://ideone.com/61wssw

Comment: @swapedoc you are no longer reading `t` every iteration and you also don't call `getchar` which probably processed the first character (a problem you mentioned in the comments above).

Comment: @ Andrei I have used getchar just below scanf

Comment: @swapedoc it's not in the loop, now is it?